# Getting the count of all rows in a paged GridView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I want to retrieve all rows count of Gridview.

When  I try this

```
 GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString()
```

it returns only active page items count.

I m using generic list of my custom class as my GridView's data source .

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you not use the count of your datasource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access your generic list's Count Property on databinding.
Where/why do you need the total row count?

According to your new information on ObjectDataSource:
Have a look at the [ObjectDataSource.Selected Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selected.aspx)

And on this example:
http://www.webswapp.com/categories/ViewSourceCode.aspx?id=ASPNET20DDLinGridViewC-GridView

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try @Tim's suggestion first as it is a better answer (he just got in before me) with it, but you can also use the Selected event of the ObjectDataSource to do this...

```
protected void ObjectDataSource_Selected(object sender,
ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{

      //if ReturnValue is a List - you might need to change this in your case.
      var list = (List<Lib.User>)e.ReturnValue;
      Response.Write(list.Count.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Lib.User]' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

Comment: Yes, that was to do with my comment "you might need to change this in your case." I copied this example out of one of my pages.